# Jquery animate move doesnt work

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Im trying to animate a car image on webpage. the opacity command work but not moving. I have put the image tag inside another big div to allow space for the image tag and its animation.

```html
<div class="blockone">
            <div class="row blockoneComingsoon">
                <h1 id="carmover" class="csoon">Click to see what we do</h1>
            </div>
            <div style="width:75%;margin:auto auto;top:10px" class="row">
                <div style="width:300px;margin:auto auto">
                    <img style="top:10px"id="car" src="/components/pg.blocks/images/car.png" width="300" class="carplace" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
</div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#car').animate({opacity: '0.1'});
                
                $('#carmover').click(function(){
               
       $('#car').animate({left:'100px',opacity: '1'});
           
                });
       
   });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have just to add position:relative to img,in this way

```
<img style="top:10px;position:relative"id="car" src="/components/pg.blocks/images/car.png" width="300" class="carplace" />
```

anyway there is a tag body in your code that is useless in that position

Answer (score 1):

You can use .addClass()...

```
.animate{
    left: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
 }

 $('#carmover').click(function(){
     $('#car').addClass('animate');
 });
```